# What does a function of proper time mean and how do you transform from proper time to real time?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, time, coordinate-systems, velocity

A covariant formulation of electromagnetism says the equation of motion of a charged particle in an electromagnetic field is $$m\frac{du_\mu}{d\tau} = qF_{\mu\nu}u^\nu.$$
But this equation is in terms of the proper time of the particle. After solving for the 4-velocity, you have a function in terms of proper time: $u_\mu(\tau)$. How does one go back to lab-frame's time, that is, get to a function $u_\mu(t)$?

The only other rule I can think of is that proper time intervals is related to lab-frame time intervals by $d\tau = dt/\gamma$. But since these are time *intervals*, I'm hesitant to just substitute $t/\gamma$ everywhere for $\tau$ in the function $u_\mu(\tau)$.

In fact, that proper time is only defined in terms of intervals (at least, this is what it seems to me) makes me wonder what is the exact meaning of $u_\mu(\tau)$ is. Is it the 4-velocity at every moment in time (not interval, but moment) according to the particle's clock?

Comment: $\tau$ is not necessarily proper time. It is an arbitrary parameter that is used to parametrise the world line. You can choose it to represent proper time though. You will have to solve the equations of motion to get $x^\mu(\tau)$.

Comment: You can usually find the difference in the elapsed proper time for 2 reference frames based on the line element of the space you're working in. But G's smith's is very much the easiest way using the other rule you know which uses the special relativity limit. $d\tau_l = d\tau_q \gamma$ where $l$ is the lab and $q$ is the charged particle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have found $u^\mu(\tau)$ then you know $\gamma(\tau)=u^0(\tau)$. You can then integrate $dt=\gamma(\tau)d\tau$ to get $t(\tau)$ and invert it to get $\tau(t)$.